MongoDB - Convert response into array of object in query
I wrote a simple query in MongoDB to get all data related to the product ID. Now I want to convert my response into an array of objects. Please see below.
Query:
db.collection.find({ "product_id": 1212 })

Getting response:
[
  {
    "product_id": 1212,
    "name": "sprit",
    "category_id": 1234,
    "category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1212,
    "name": "sprit",
    "category_id": 2122,
    "category": "soda"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1212,
    "name": "sprit",
    "category_id": 2121,
    "category": "mocktail"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 1212,
    "name": "sprit",
    "category_id": 2121,
    "category": "mocktail"
  }
]

I want to convert the data in a different format by MongoDB query and remove duplicate category_id.
Required response:
[
  {
    "product_id": 1212,
    "name": "sprit",
    "categogies": [
      {
        "category_id": 1234,
        "category": "drink"
      },
      {
        "category_id": 2122,
        "category": "soda"
      },
      {
        "category_id": 2121,
        "category": "mocktail"
      }
    ]
  }
]


Group by product_id via $group and add distinct document into the categogies array via $addToSet.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "product_id": 1212
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$product_id",
      name: {
        $first: "$name"
      },
      categogies: {
        $addToSet: {
          "category_id": "$category_id",
          "category": "$category"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      product_id: "$_id",
      name: "$name",
      categogies: "$categogies"
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

this is correct, but there are many other columns like price, saleQuantity, quantity, etc.  I have mentioned only product_Id and name. How can I use all column

Hi, so you should use $$ROOT to add the whole document into array. Then with $unset stage to remove the unwanted field in the categogies array. Demo

{
"product_id": 1212,
"name": "sprit",
"price" : 223,
"quantity" : 100,
"category_id": 2121,
"category": "mocktail"
}

I need to add all keys on same level except category because we have convert category into categories in array of object.

Or are you looking the result data like this demo?
